# NSString compression based on repeating substrings, or differences between 2 strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring, compression

i have stream of base64 encoded image strings and there are lots of repeating substrings. I would like to save some space by compressing them somehow (and decompressing them back).
I am also open for another solutions of saving space, like sending only diffecences between two strings.

What is the best practice to do so ?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit** 
What in case I need to compress data on windows and decompress in iOS ? 
On osx I'll try this lib https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using gzip compression.  You can find a simple category for NSData by Nick Lockwood, called [GZIP](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP).  It's trivial to write a category on `NSString` that does the two step conversion for you: `NSString`->`NSData`->Compressed `NSData`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, but what in case I need to compress data on windows and decompress in iOS ?

Comment: GZIP is the same everywhere.  If your encoder and decoder are to spec, the platform for each does not matter.